# In ASD do you divide elastic or ultimate strength?

Tags: structural-engineering

In Allowable Stress Design (ASD) method, to find the allowable stress, do you divide the ultimate stress or the elastic stress (where the material becomes plastic) by the factor of safety? For example when using ASCE 7?

Comment: "ASD" is a general concept, the details of how it is used will be given in the applicable Code or manual that you are using. You will either need to [edit] your question to add what code you are following, or you will have to look it up in the code.

Comment: ASCE 7 (Minimum Design Loads for Buildings and Other Structures) is a book of load combinations. The details that you are looking for would be in a manual such as AISC 360 (Specification for Steel Buildings). This is a portion of what is commonly known as the "AISC Steel Construction Manual".